# How to display data in ckeditor from mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I am new in this field, I used ckeditor but I don't know how to display data in ckeditor through mysql..

**My code is**

```
$CKeditor = new CKeditor();
$CKeditor->BasePath = 'manage-site/';
$CKeditor->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html';
$CKeditor->config['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'] = 'browser/browser.php?type=Images';
$CKeditor->config['filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl'] = 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash';
$CKeditor->config['filebrowserUploadUrl'] = 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files';
$CKeditor->config['filebrowserImageUploadUrl'] = 'uploader/uploader.php?type=Images';
$CKeditor->config['filebrowserFlashUploadUrl'] = 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash';
$CKeditor->editor('page_desc','**page_desc**');
```

**For display content I use**

```
<?php echo stripslashes($details[0]["page_desc"]); ?>
```

I wanted to display on the place of `Page_desc(last Line of Code)`. How to do that?

Comment: You mean display the ckeditor on bottom page or wat ?

Comment: $CKeditor->editor('page_desc','**i wanted print here**'); this code echo stripslashes($details[0]["page_desc"]); @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: You're using framework or core php ?

Comment: Core php @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: Have you included `<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>` and then did `$ckeditor->editor('mycustomname');` ?

Comment: Yes i have used it 
Ref:http://www.uandblog.com/How-to-Integrate-CKEditor-in-Web-Page-using-PHP @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: Can you do one thing, shall i suggest you a very simple thing to do that ?

Comment: posted you the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply download the ckeditor package and do this simple 2 step

**Step 1 :** Include the `ckeditor.js` from your file

`<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>`

**Step 2 :** Include the class name as `ckeditor` to your `textarea`

Then you can see the ckeditor with simple step

**Note :** Make sure the ckeditor.js is in the proper path

Hope this helps you